# Amazon SNS topic is not triggering lambda even with confirmed role applied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an lambda that is currently being triggered by dynamodb stream. It works perfectly. However, I'm trying to add an sns topic to trigger the lambda. In the configuration of the aws console, the sns topic appears to successfully be set to trigger the lambda. However, when I publish to the sns topic, it does not trigger the lambda. I expected this to be a permission problem, however it looks like I have the correct permissions.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "default",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowExecutionFromSNS",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "sns.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:##############:function:<<topicname>>",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:##############:<<topicname>>"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: SNS has correct role to trigger lambda execution ?

Comment: Check all spellings. Check that the Lambda function is subscribed to the SNS topic. Check that the trigger is enabled. Remove the ArnLike condition temporarily and retry.